# Word VBA Application Event fires more times when more documents opened

Tags: events, vba, ms-word

I have the following problem. I wrote simple macro which shows MsgBox before print dialog. Here is source:

```
Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "aaaaa"
End Sub

Private Sub Document_New()
        Set App = Application
End Sub
```

When I open one document from template with this macro, everything is OK. But I have a problem when I open two documents from this template at same time. When I click to print button, MsgBox shown up twice. Any ideas?

Edit:
When I create document from this template and create another new document, which isnt't based on this template (both of this documents are opened at the same time) and I print from that new empty document, MsgBox shown up. This is also wrong right?

Answer (score 2):

You have created application-level events that fire every time any document is being printed.  They are triggered once for every document that has this code in it, so every time you print a document you will get the msgbox once for every open document that has the code in it, whether or not the document that's printing has the code in it.

So, the behaviors aren't wrong, although clearly they are not what you want.

You should put the Before_Print event in the ThisDocument module of your template.  That way the event will only happen once, and only when the document being printed has the code in it.

Comment: As you said, this will work only when one document has the code in it. But if you have multiple copies of that document open, each with their own `BeforePrint` trigger, it will still fire on each document.

Answer (score 2):

You could put a check in your App_DocumentBeforePrint sub to check whether the instance of the application object which is firing the event is the instance that contains the active document:

```
If Me <> ActiveDocument Then Exit Sub
```